# ipSec VPN configuration, VLANs advertised

Tags: vpn, vlan, site-to-site-vpn

We are in the process of setting up an ipSec VPN between 2 locations. There are various encryption methods, algorythms and preshared keys to set up. Network1 will have access to specific VLANs on Network2 and vise versa.

The questions is:
Should side 1 have the exact same target VLANs configured as the ones advertised on side 2?
Or can for example side 2 advertise more VLANs than the actual destination ones configured on side 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to setting up VPNs, PSKs, cipers and other buzzwords, it's worthy to read some books to understand that network sites don't advertise VLANs. At least usually. Unless you are really-really sure about what you're doing, because linking VLANs through WAN and using a high latency network is generally a really bad idea.

But if you want a formal answer - no, you don't care about VLAN numbers on the sites, because VLANs are on 2nd layer of OSI model, and you will link your sites on the 3rd level of OSI model.